# Are you sure you want to leave this page?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, editing

This has never happened before on SE, not even earlier today in a different stack.

I wrote a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4354524/adding-or-multiplying-probability) and clicked "post."  Immediate pop-up "Are you sure you want to leave this page?"  I assumed (incorrectly) that something had gone wrong.  So I said No and tried again.  oops! duplicate post.

Then I saw a typo and tried to fix it.  When I clicked Save, same pop-up, with a busy spinner on the Save button.  Clicked yes (leave), and saw that the edits had actually been saved.

Comment: It did not happen when I posted this question.  However, when I edited the question it did happen, AND an earlier version of this comment disappeared.

Comment: @WGroleau I just got basically the same behavior as you, using Microsoft Edge on a Windows 10 machine. When I clicked "Cancel", my answer showed as being blank! However, refreshing showed that the edits were saved. Like you, this has never happened before, and I haven't made any recent machine changes (e.g., any updates). Thus, I suspect SE has changed something recently to cause this to happen. I'm not sure if this is just on the Math site, but you may wish to check if it's also on other sites and, if so, write a bug report on the general [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) SE site.

Comment: @WGroleau FYI, this is already reported on Meta at [Editing a post leads to a weird behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375054/562482). A [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375054/editing-a-post-leads-to-a-weird-behavior#comment1249418_375054) there indicates it's also been reported on meta StackOverflow at [Getting "You have started editing this post. Abandon this edit?" when saving an edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415234/11726740).

Comment: Ditto for me, WGroleau, and @JohnOmielan! Using Firefox.

Comment: I can confirm it occurs on Safari when you edit an answer too.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with posting answers as well.

Comment: Same error happens to me, too (using both latest Firefox and Chrome on Win10)

Comment: Yes, I am seeing this when editing answers.

Comment: The devs are working on this bug. [Thanks for notifying us, we were able to reproduce it and will try to fix this asap. We'll keep you posted on this question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415234/getting-you-have-started-editing-this-post-abandon-this-edit-when-saving-an?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment889069_415234)

Answer (score 10):

First of all: thanks a lot to everybody for notifying us about this issue. We have been able to reproduce and fix the issue. Please do let us know (in a comment to this answer) if you're still encountering any issues with this.